# Select one line first, afterwards the second

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following problem: My goal is to get two lines as a result at once. It's two times the same "select" statement, just with another ID. With my code I just get the second line. How is it possible to get both lines at once?

```
select 
table1.attr1 + table2.attr2 as total,
table1.id
FROM  table1, table2
WHERE table.id = 1 AND table2.id = 1;

select 
table1.attr1 + table2.attr2 as total,
table1.id
FROM  table1, table2
WHERE  table.id = 2 AND table2.id = 2;
```

Comment: `UNION ALL` between your queries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use explicit `joins` with `on` clause:

```
select t1.attr1 + t2.attr2 as total
     , t1.id
FROM  table1 t1 join table2 t2 on t1.id = t2.id
WHERE t1.id in (1, 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Modify your join condition:

```
SELECT
    table1.attr1 + table2.attr2 as total,
    table1.id
FROM  table1, table2
WHERE (table.id = 1 AND table2.id = 1)
    OR (table.id = 2 AND table2.id = 2)
```